# Extension is missing in category page in Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have popular extension in Chrome Web Store in category Web Development.

For some reason it is missing in category view page, no matter how long I scroll the list down: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/11-web-development

Any ideas of what is the reason and how to fix it? I hope someone from Chrome Web Store team can contact me

Comment: I think this is probably off-topic (generally questions about app stores, and especially an app store's curation are off-topic), but I can't even observe your problem. I see your extension listed in the 12th row under "More recommendations". Is it possible that Google is filtering it out because you already have it installed, or because you're logged into the account that is the author of the extension? What happens if you look in an different browser while logged out?

Comment: Was advised to post on stackoverflow on Google Help forums by Google employee to reach Chrome Web Store team :-) It's great you see it, I'm not even if extension is uninstalled and I'm logged out and in Private mode. May depend on Store region, I'm in Russian one

Comment: Note I removed the link from the question (it's still in revision history if someone needs to look it up), as it can be seen as spammy. Answer forthcoming.

Comment: Also, found a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome filters out extensions you already have installed from the "browse" view.

I can assure I can find your specific extension in that category.

You can check yourself from another browser profile (**this carries over to Incognito**, so it MUST be a profile without this extension).

---

Note, trying to contact CWS team through here is a poor idea. One can try [the bugtracker](https://crbug.com/) for general issues, as at least some CWS issues are tracked there, and there's a (well-hidden) [developer support form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/) for CWS.